# Invariant tensors derived from an affine connection

Tags: differential-geometry

Given $\nabla$,an affine connection in the tangent bundle of a manifold $M,$ we have two very important and cannonical tensors asociated to $\nabla,$ namely the torsion tensor $T$ and the curvature tensor $R.$

**Are there any other tensors derived from the connection $\nabla$ and independent from $T$ and $R?$**

A tensor will be independent from $T$ and $R$ if it is not produced from $T$ and $R$ by differentiation(covariant) or by an algebraic equation like the tensor product.